# WebAuthenticator -> You must subclass the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity and create an IntentFilter for it which matches your callbackUrl

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials, webauthenticator

**Expected Behavior :** app should open website for login

**Actual Behavior :**
error encountered You must subclass the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity and create an IntentFilter for it which matches your callbackUrl.

**Screenshots :**

Error

[image]

Subclass

[image]

Comment: you can try to overide the OnResume method in your MainActivity class, to call back into Xamarin.Essentials,`protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnResume();
}`

Comment: Hi, already does this but still not working.

Comment: Please check your call back Url is correct?

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 5):

You should write DataScheme="xamarinessentials" and DataHost="ABC" as properties into IntentFilterAttribute.

Answer (score 4):

in MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(label="your_app", ....)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "your_app")]

var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
        new Uri("your_Auth_URL"),
        new Uri("your_app")); //THIS MUST BE SAME AS YOUR DATASCHEME

var accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
```

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android#using-webauthenticator